# ¿Cambiar TimeOut al hacer perticiones a un WebService?

Tags: java, android, webservice

Tengo la siguiente clase para hacer peticiones a un WebService, todas las peticiones funcionan correctamente, lo que quiero saber es como reducir el TimeOut para que no espere alrededor de 30s para decir que no hay conexión con el WebService.

```
public class WebServiceManager {

    public static void CallWebServiceOperation(final WebServiceManagerInterface caller,
                                               final String webServiceURL,
                                               final String resourceName,
                                               final String operation,
                                               final String methodType,
                                               final String payload,
                                               final String userState) {

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(webServiceURL + "/" + resourceName + "/" + operation);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(methodType);
                    httpURLConnection.getOutputStream().write(payload.getBytes());
                    int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                        int charIn = 0;
                        while ((charIn = in.read()) != -1) {
                            stringBuffer.append((char) charIn);
                        }
                        caller.WebServiceMessageReceived(userState, stringBuffer.toString());
                    }
                } catch (Exception error) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) tiene dos métodos que pueden ser ùtiles:

> **setConnectTimeout()** con la cual puedes establecer los tiempos de
>   caducidad de conexión.
>
> **setReadTimeout()** con la cual puedes establecer los tiempos de
>   caducidad de lectura a través de los métodos

Para ambos mètodos se define el tiempo en millisegundos.

Para el caso que comentas ( reducir el `TimeOut` para que no espere alrededor de 30s  ) puedes usar **setConnectTimeout()**

Te sugiero leer el artículo:
[Operaciones HTTP En Android Con El Cliente HttpURLConnection](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/01/android-httpurlconnection/)

Answer (score 1):

Ajuste el `TimeOut` con el método `setConnectTimeout()` de la clase `HttpURLConnection`. Funciona bien, al pasarse el TimeOut pasa a una excepción que puedes aprovechar para cambiar alguna bandera que diga que no hay conexión al Web Service.